# Passing Image URL as Parameter To SSRS Webservice

Tags: web-services, url, ssl, reporting-services

How must I pass Image URLs as parameters to SSRS under context of SSL?

I am using the SSRS web service to generate and save a report and I send the image URLs of graphs used in the report as parameters. Under normal non-SSL this works 100%, but under SSL I get a timeout Soap-Exception.

I have thus far tried:

- Non-Secured URL: Causes Timeout.
- Secured URL: Generates Report Without Images
- Non-Secured IP URL: Causes Timeout
- Secured IP URL: Generates Report Without Images
- Filesystem Path: Generates Report Without Images

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found the answer to my problem. Where I create the URL for the image on the server, I had it on normal HTTP protocol, but with a secured port. So I removed the port, and it seems to work 100% in SSL.